# Erro ao tentar passar ticket[i] = i;

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Testes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] ticket = new int[5];
            string[] nome = new string[5];
            for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bem vindo, digite seu nome: ");
                ticket[i] = i;
                nome[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Ticket número {0} do Sr. {1}", ticket[i], nome[i]);
                Console.WriteLine("Pressione Enter");

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }   
    }
}
```

O erro que aparece é:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Testes.exe

Comment: O erro ocorre na primeira execução ou executa corretamente um x de iterações?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O seu array está declarado como tendo 5 items:

```
int[] ticket = new int[5];
```

O problema do seu código é estar a assumir que o primeiro item do array tem como indice 1.
Os indices dos arrays em C# e na maioria das linguagens começam em 0.

Da forma como está o seu *for* o código irá aceder ao item indice 5 o que ultrapassa o comprimento do array.

Altere o seu ciclo *for* para:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Uma forma de evitar este tipo de erro é usar, na condição, a propriedade `Length` do *array*:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ticket.Length; i++)
```